# If $ { z_1 - 2z_2 }\over { 2 - z_1{\bar z_2} } $ is unimodulus and $z_2$ is not unimodulus then find $|z_1|$ .

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

$$ \left| {{z_1 - 2z_2 }\over { 2 - z_1{\bar z_2} } } \right| $$

$$ \implies  | { z_1 - 2z_2 } | = |  { 2 - z_1{\bar z_2} } | $$

I dont know how to proceed now .

Comment: @Aniket I have deleted the previous . This is the original now . Please remove your comment . It happened due to slow internet , I couldnt know if my question got posted or not , so I rewrote it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of the formula $z\bar{z}=|z|^2$, then
$$\left| \dfrac{z_1-2z_2}{2-z_1\bar{z_2}} \right|=1$$ just means that
$$ \dfrac{z_1-2z_2}{2-z_1\bar{z_2}}\dfrac{\bar{z_1}-2\bar{z_2}}{2-\bar{z_1}z_2}=1.$$
Then a direct computation gives you $|z_1|^2=4$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=z_1,\ y=z_2$ and use $b(z)$ for the conjugate of $z.$ Then the squared moduli of $x-2y$ and of $2-xb(y)$ are assumed equal. The second modulus is the same as that of $xb(y)-2.$ Now use that for any $z$ the squared modulus of $z$ is given by $zb(z),$ and so
$$(x-2y)(b(x)-2b(y))=(xb(y)-2)(b(x)y-2).$$
When multiplied out, some terms cancel, and after algebra you get 
$$xb(x)(1-yb(y))=4(1-yb(y)).$$
At this point since $y$ is not unimodular the factor $(1=yb(y))$ is nonzero so can be cancelled, and so $xb(x)=4.$ In the original variables this means that $z_1\bar{z_1}=4.$